# change Thai month names to English using JS

Tags: javascript, date

I have this date `21 ต.ค. 2022 06:10 PM` and i would like to change into `21 Oct 2022 06:10 PM`.

This is my code:

```js
var date = "21 ต.ค. 2022 06:10 PM";

var monthNamesThai = ["ม.ค.", "ก.พ.", "มี.ค.", "เม.ย.", "พ.ค.", "มิ.ย.", "ก.ค.", "ส.ค.", "ก.ย.", "ต.ค.", "พ.ย.", "ธ.ค."];

// var monthNamesEng = ["01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06",  "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12"];
var monthNamesEng = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "June", "July", "Aug", "Sept", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
  
var d = new Date(date);

console.log("Change date " + d + " = " + ('0' + d.getDate()).slice(-2) + " " + monthNamesEng[d.getMonth()] + " " + d.getFullYear());
```

in which I get the output: `Change date Invalid Date = aN undefined NaN`. Is there a simple way to change the Thai month names to English without using Moment.js? Thanks in advance

Comment: isn't `new Date(string)` require the date in a certain format? and this is why `momentjs` is important. dealing with [time is difficult](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY).

Comment: his format is correct expect for the month part.

Comment: @Layhout in ecmascript standard, [only one date format is strictly specified](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date-time-string-format). the rest are client dependent. i'm just giving heads up in case string manipulation hits edge cases or something ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var date = "21 ต.ค. 2022 06:10 PM";

var monthNamesThai = ["ม.ค.", "ก.พ.", "มี.ค.", "เม.ย.", "พ.ค.", "มิ.ย.", "ก.ค.", "ส.ค.", "ก.ย.", "ต.ค.", "พ.ย.", "ธ.ค."];

// var monthNamesEng = ["01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06",  "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12"];
var monthNamesEng = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "June", "July", "Aug", "Sept", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];

const thaiMonth = date.substring(date.indexOf(" ") + 1, date.indexOf(" ") + 5) 
console.log(date.replace(thaiMonth, monthNamesEng[monthNamesThai.indexOf(thaiMonth)]))
```

Comment: Do not post an answer with merely codes. While your solution can be useful, you should also explain why the code will fix the problem that was described in the question.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you Thai date always has the same format as this one, otherwise this will not work.

```js
let date = "21 ต.ค. 2022 06:10 PM";

let monthNamesThai = ["ม.ค.", "ก.พ.", "มี.ค.", "เม.ย.", "พ.ค.", "มิ.ย.", "ก.ค.", "ส.ค.", "ก.ย.", "ต.ค.", "พ.ย.", "ธ.ค."];

let monthNamesEng = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "June", "July", "Aug", "Sept", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];

// change Thai month to english month
let englishDate = date.split(" ");
englishDate.splice(1, 1, monthNamesEng[monthNamesThai.indexOf(date.split(" ")[1])]);
englishDate = englishDate.join(" ");
  
let d = new Date(englishDate);

console.log("Change date " + d + " = " + ('0' + d.getDate()).slice(-2) + " " + monthNamesEng[d.getMonth()] + " " + d.getFullYear());
```